# Best way to loop the angular 4 with bootstrap columns?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to loop my list in bootstrap columns.

1. In the first row, I would like to show three columns
2. In the second row, I would like to show two columns
3. In the third row, I would like to show only one column

The code is below.

```
<div *ngFor="let watch of List;let i = index;" >  
    <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4': watch.rowtype == 'three-view', 'col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6': watch.rowtype == 'two-view',  'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12': watch.rowtype == 'one-view'}"
         style="text-align:center; background-color:rgb(0, 183, 255);">{{watch.name}}
    </div>
    <div>{{watch.value}}</div>
</div>
```

It is displaying each column in a single row. Not showing like three, two and one.

Comment: did you define <div class="row"> before ngFor ?

Comment: @Robert If we define the row before ngFor all the columns are displaying in a single row.

Comment: Then you probably need another loop for the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If we define the row before ngFor all the columns are displaying in a single row."

Not if you add `[ngClass]` to the same element that is being iterated:

```
<div class="row">  
    <div *ngFor="let watch of List;let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4': watch.rowtype == 'three-view', 'col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6': watch.rowtype == 'two-view',  'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12': watch.rowtype == 'one-view'}"
         style="text-align:center; background-color:rgb(0, 183, 255);">{{watch.name}}
    </div>
    <div>{{watch.value}}</div>
</div>
```

You also don't need those `rowType` fields, you could do something like this:

```
[ngClass]="{'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4': (index / 3 < 1)
```

Comment: `[ngClass]="{'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4': (index / 3 < 1)` for three columns it will work and the two and single columns can we use this?

Comment: Well sure, I was just making an example. You can change the condition a bit, I'm on a mobile now so can't really code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you are missing the class "row" in you *ngFor-div:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let watch of List;let i = index;" >  
   <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4': watch.rowtype == 'three-view', 'col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6': watch.rowtype == 'two-view',  'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12': watch.rowtype == 'one-view'}"
     style="text-align:center; background-color:rgb(0, 183, 255);">{{watch.name}}
</div>
   <div>{{watch.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be div with `{{watch.value}}` should be inside `<div [ngClass]="` like this?

```
            <div *ngFor="let watch of List;let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4': watch.rowtype == 'three-view', 'col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6': watch.rowtype == 'two-view',  'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12': watch.rowtype == 'one-view'}"
                 style="text-align:center; background-color:rgb(0, 183, 255);">
                 <div>{{watch.name}}<div>
                 <div>{{watch.value}}</div>
            </div>
```